My desktop files disappeared after I installed the Sonoma update
I use an Apple M1 Mac and I recently installed the Sonoma 14.0 update. Ever since I did that, all the files on my desktop vanished. They haven’t been deleted: when I use the Finder all the files and folders that were on my desktop are there. Does anyone know how to return the files back to the desktop as they were?
I've tried dragging the files back to the Desktop but a message appears saying that the file will be removed from the cloud which doesn't sound good at all.
